# How do I export a module from a try/catch block in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-import

I am trying to develop for a package that only runs on some systems. There is a "mock" version of the package that exists as well.

I'd like a "module" that I can `import` from my main that automatically falls back to the "mock" version of the package when the main package fails to import (either because it did not install because of os/engine restrictions or it failed on startup).

This is what I have so far:

```
import { Gpio as GpioClass, GpioBank as GpioBankClass, Notifier as NotifierClass } from 'pigpio';

let pigpio: {
  Gpio: typeof GpioClass;
  GpioBank: typeof GpioBankClass;
  Notifier: typeof NotifierClass;
};

try {
  pigpio = require('pigpio');
} catch (e) {
  process.env.PIGPIO_NO_LOGGING = 'yes';
  pigpio = require('pigpio-mock');
}

export const { Gpio, GpioBank, Notifier } = pigpio;
```

This kind of works but seems to cause some import errors/ordering issues with other parts of my code.

I suspect that using `import` and `export` will be better in the long run. Maybe this is a flawed assumption. I'm still not 100% clear on how exactly `import`/`export` works.

I've tried using the "async" `import(...)` function to no avail:

```
import { Gpio as GpioClass, GpioBank as GpioBankClass, Notifier as NotifierClass } from 'pigpio';

let pigpio: Promise<{
  Gpio: typeof GpioClass;
  GpioBank: typeof GpioBankClass;
  Notifier: typeof NotifierClass;
}>;

try {
  pigpio = import('pigpio');
} catch (e) {
  process.env.PIGPIO_NO_LOGGING = 'yes';
  pigpio = import('pigpio-mock');
}

// This doesn't work. Cannot use top level await.
export const { Gpio, GpioBank, Notifier } = await pigpio;
```

Is there some part of how `export` works that I'm missing? Or maybe it's like how you can `await` a non-`async` function as long as it returns a Promise and I just need to `module.exports = import(...)`? That doesn't seem to work however.

The cherry on top would be to get the type information correct for TypeScript.

Comment: Wait for (and vote for) [top-level await in TypeScript](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/25988).

Comment: Best you can currently do is to use the dynamic `require` solution, or do all the setup during the build/install of the module.